# How to deploy node app dependencies? How is possible to ensure to install certain versions of a package with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

What's the best way to deploy the dependencies for a node app. How is possible to ensure to install certain versions of a package with npm. Are there like recipe files as the requirements.txt with python's pip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `package.json` specifies a module's dependencies.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

```
{ "dependencies" :
  { "foo" : "1.0.0 - 2.9999.9999"
  , "bar" : ">=1.0.2 <2.1.2"
  , "baz" : ">1.0.2 <=2.3.4"
  , "boo" : "2.0.1"
  , "qux" : "<1.0.0 || >=2.3.1 <2.4.5 || >=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
  , "asd" : "http://asdf.com/asdf.tar.gz"
  , "til" : "~1.2"
  , "elf" : "~1.2.3"
  , "two" : "2.x"
  , "thr" : "3.3.x"
  , "lat" : "latest"
  , "dyl" : "file:../dyl"
  }
}
```